# Xcode: different build setting options for different configurations. Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, configuration, build

In my Xcode project, I'm looking at the "Target Info" window, "Build" tab. In the list of compiler settings, for most of my configurations ("Release", "Distribution", and "Ad Hoc"), there's a settings section called "GCC 4.2 - Preprocessing". When I switch to my "Debug" configuration, that section goes away.

What can I do to make my "Debug" configuration show these settings as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Ive never seen anything like this. Are you using xconfig files? Could it be dependant on some other setting that you have made in your debug config?

Comment: I have no idea. And I don't know anything about xconfig files, other than they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Debug configuration's Base SDK set to a missing SDK? Xcode gets the specs for what flags the compiler supports from the configured base SDK. If it's missing, then Xcode doesn't know what compiler to show flags for.

Your Debug configuration might build correctly if you're using the Overview popup to set an override SDK. But since that's an override setting, the build setting inspector doesn't know about it. You have to set the base SDK to something valid, even if you're overriding it with the Active SDK popup.